# C# Remote Performance Counters with multiple Counters

Tags: c#, session, performancecounter

I try to use the following Code for Performance Counters from a Remote Computer.
getAll(counters) returns a Array of String which contains all Performance Counter Pathes I want to get. But it doesn't work.

result contains nothing, after invoking the command.
Any Ideas why this is not working as it should?

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

pipeline.Commands.AddScript(@"$sessions = New-PSSession -ComputerName " + serverName + Environment.NewLine
    + @"Invoke-Command -session $sessions -ScriptBlock {Get-Counter -counter " + getAll(counterNames) + " }" + Environment.NewLine
    + "Remove-PSSession -Session $sessions" + Environment.NewLine
    + "exit" + Environment.NewLine + "exit" + Environment.NewLine);


result = pipeline.Invoke();
```

For Example getAll returns this

```
getAll(counterNames)
{string[2]}
    [0]: "\\Memory\\Available Bytes"
    [1]: "\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time"
```

I use for local Power Shell Commands this and it is working with getAll correctly

```
psh.AddCommand("get-counter");
                    psh.AddParameter("computername", serverName);
                    psh.AddParameter("counter", getAll(counterNames));

                    result = this.PowershellInvoke(psh);
```

But I need a solution for remote Computers and I need a Session for this.

Comment: Did you try using `Logman.exe` which comes out of the box with Windows OS ?

Comment: when I replace getAll(counterNames) with for example "\Memory\Available Bytes", "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" it is working. So there is something wrong with the conversion from the StringArray to the PowerShell command

Comment: What does `getAll()` function do ? Can you pls share that ?

Comment: it just returns a Array of Stringget All(counterNames)
{string[2]}
    [0]: "\\Memory\\Available Bytes"
    [1]: "\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time"

Comment: So, it is not same as comma separated string values as you said earlier, i.e. `when you replace getAll(...) with comma-separated strings` it works !

Comment: yes, your are right. But its easier for me to put a Array of String instead of hard coded text in it. And normally that should work as you can see in the example code below

Comment: Check this - http://poshcode.org/2216 & http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/12/29/arguments-for-remote-commands.aspx

Comment: Can i move to answer if you are satisified such that you can `accept` that ?